# how to trim whitespace between strings in selenium xpath python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I want to find elements containing name and age.

But Name can contain whitespace like "Jo hn", So I want to remove whitespace between strings.

So I made code below, but SyntaxError. How can I do this?

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="Nlist"]/section/ul/li/a/span[contains(text().replace(" ", ""),"' + NAME + '") and contains(.,"' + AGE + '")]')
```

`text().replace(" ", "")` is Syntax Error. Is there any method?

I need to do this when find elements because speed.

Comment: Selenium only supports xpath 1.0, unfortunately (this could be done with later versions of xpath), so you may have to do this in stages. Please edit your question with a couple of representative html snippets.

Comment: @JackFleeting check my answer below and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @supputuri - you did it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the sample html used to trim the space(s) with in name and used contains to match the partial text.

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  <span>s upputuri-100</span>
  <span>s upp uturi-100</span>
   </body>
</html>
```

You can use `translate` method to replace the white space(s) with the desired char/empty. Below the xpath to get the span that contains `supputuri` and `100`.

```
//span[contains(translate(.,' ' ,''),'supputuri')][contains(.,'100')]
```

[image]

Comment: It only trim leading and trailing white-space, not between strings

Comment: Updated the answer with sample html and the solution. Please share the html of the span if the solution does not work.

Comment: It works for me, too.  Thank you. I test at selenium latest version.

Comment: Cool, glad that we were helpful.

Comment: Totally forgot about `translate()`; +1!